# Monitor and block activities starting on android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have to implement a parental-control-type app with a pretty simple concept: whenever an app is launched (a game, photo gallery etc) my app (which probably should be a service) will detect the attempt to launch and display a screen requesting for a password. If the password is ok, it will keep launching the app, otherwise it'll block it.

Any idea on where to begin?

Also, do I need the tablet to be rooted?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Comment: I found nothing on the internet, so I implemented a background service that continuously checks the running apps. When the top app is one of the restricted apps, it simply launches a block screen activity requesting for password. If the password fails, launch a home intent with clear task flags. If password is ok, just finish the screen and save a 5-minute permission for the restricted app.